# Concurrent Modification exception when only values of Hashmap are modified

Tags: java, concurrentmodification

I have code like below, in which the inner loop modifies the Hashmap, but only in a way that no new keys are added or deleted, but only the values are updated. Does this qualifies as modification of a Hashmap, for Concurrent Modification Exception to be thrown ? In current tests that I have done, I haven't found any exception to be thrown though.

```
for(String variable:variableMap.descendingKeySet()) {
        for (String innerVariable : variableMap.keySet()) {
            variableMap.put(innerVariable, variableMap.get(innerVariable).replace("$" + variable, variableMap.get(variable)));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Note that you can replace the inner loop with `variableMap.replaceAll((k, v) -> v.replace("$" + variable, variableMap.get(variable)))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [Javadoc of `HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html):

> The iterators returned by all of this class's "collection view
>   methods" are *fail-fast*: if the map is **structurally modified** at any
>   time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the
>   iterator's own `remove` method, the iterator will throw a
>   `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Now what is "structurally modified" ?

> A structural modification is any operation that adds or deletes one or
>   more mappings; **merely changing the value associated with a key** that an
>   instance already contains is **not** a structural modification.

So, no, you won't get a `ConcurrentModificationException` if you only modify the value of the key.

Comment: To add one point: You can also use `entrySet`'s `setValue` to set value for a key (Similar to setting a value for an *existing* key as in the OP and hence the same behavior)